# SQL How to Combine Multiple Fields with Case and Sum Statements

Tags: sql

I am trying to aggregate my data by first renaming multiple data points as a similar name, and summing the quantities for those.  I have tried the following:

```
select  CASE
when Category='1' or Category='2' Then 'TEST'
when Category='3' Then 'ACTUAL' 
else category end As Activity, 
sum(case when quantity >0 then quantity end) from DataBase 
Group By category
```

The output is this:

```
Activity   |  Quantity  
  Test     |    8  
  Actual   |    20  
  Test     |    2
```

However, I want it to look like this:

```
Activity   |  Quantity  
Test       |  10  
Actual     |  20
```

Comment: please edit the question, tag with appropriate database platform, and show example table data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some databases allow aliases in the `GROUP BY`, but not all.  You can repeat the `CASE` expression:

```
select (case when Category in ('1', '2') then 'TEST'
             when Category = '3' then 'ACTUAL'
             else category
        end) As Activity,
      sum(case when quantity >0 then quantity end)
from DataBase
group by (case when Category in ('1', '2') then 'TEST'
               when Category = '3' then 'ACTUAL'
               else category
          end);
```

Note that some databases would allow you to write:

```
group by Activity
```

Answer (score 0):

Other databases allow you to group by the ordinal number of the entry in the select list.

And I always get unpleasant shudders - like a chalk screeching over a blackboard - whenever someone mixes Numerics or Integers with strings in the same column / expression - so I changed your `ELSE` clause in the `CASE` expression to return `'other'` rather than the numeric 'other' category ...

Like here:

```
WITH
input(category,quantity) AS (
          SELECT 1,8
UNION ALL SELECT 2,2
UNION ALL SELECT 3,20
)
SELECT
  CASE category
    WHEN 1 THEN 'test'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'test'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'actual'
    ELSE 'other'
   END AS activity
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN QUANTITY > 0 THEN quantity END) AS qty
FROM input
GROUP BY 1;

-- out  activity | qty 
-- out ----------+-----
-- out  test     |  10
-- out  actual   |  20
```